# SQL query condition not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a search script with pagination but can't get it to work properly.

Here is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM server_data WHERE trash = '0' AND server_address LIKE '%$search%' OR title LIKE '%$search%' OR short_desc LIKE '%$search%'";
```

This is to count how many results there are in the database.

Here is my query for the actual data:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM server_data WHERE trash = '0' AND server_address LIKE '%$search%' OR title LIKE '%$search%' OR short_desc LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
```

For some reason, this is returning results where trash = 1 and trash = 0, when it should only be returning where trash = 0 obviously. Anybody have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: `WHERE trash = '0' AND (server_address LIKE '%$search%' OR title LIKE '%$search%' OR short_desc LIKE '%$search%') ORDER BY id DESC $limit";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parenthesis

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM server_data WHERE trash = '0' AND (server_address LIKE '%$search%' OR title LIKE '%$search%' OR short_desc LIKE '%$search%') ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
```

Without parenthesis your query is evaluated as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM server_data WHERE (trash = '0' AND server_address LIKE '%$search%') OR title LIKE '%$search%' OR short_desc LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
```

The reason for this is that `AND` is "strong" than `OR` (it's like in math where multiplication is stronger than addition: 3*5+3=15+3=18).

Btw. please make sure `$search` is properly escaped, otherwise you allow SQL injection.

Comment: Would using a prepared statement be good enough as far as preventing SQL injection?

Comment: Yes, that would fix this. Maybe also $limit has to be handled (at least casted to int).